# Reusing react/redux component on different routes connected to different part of state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, redux

I am running into a problem because I have a fairly complex component that renders a list of items. The list of items is taken directly from the redux state tree. I want to have 2 separate routes that reuse this same component, but each of them will connect to a different list from the state tree.

Here is a simplified example:

Starting with the state tree:

```
state = {
    fruits: ['apple', 'banana', 'grape', 'pear'],
    vegetables: ['celery', 'carrot', 'cucumber']
}
```

and a simple listing component

```
class ListView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => 
          <div key={index}>{item}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    items: state.fruits
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ListView)
```

The higher level App component looks like this:

```
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default connect()(App)
```

And the routes look like this:

```
  <Route path='/' component={App}>
    <IndexRedirect to='fruits' />
    <Route path='fruits' component={ListView} />
    <Route path='vegetables' component={ListView} />
  </Route>
```

So right now the ListView component is connected to the fruits part of the redux state. However I would like to utilize the route structure here so '/fruits' and '/vegetables' will both use the same component, but '/fruits' will list the fruits while '/vegetables' will list the vegetables.

The obvious work around is to create a completely new and identical component class and change the mapStateToProps method to connect to the vegetables array.

Is there a way to reuse this component but have access to different parts of the state tree in each?

Comment: Made an update to my answer to include using the components in your router.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From your ListView, you could export both FruitsList and VeggiesList as separate components, then display the correct one based on route.

```
class ListView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.items.map((item, index) => 
          <div key={index}>{item}</div>
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

function mapStateToPropsVeggies(state) {
  return {
    items: state.veggies
  }
}

function mapStateToPropsFruits(state) {
  return {
    items: state.fruits
  }
}

const VeggiesList = connect(mapStateToPropsVeggies)(ListView);
const FruitsList = connect(mapStateToPropsFruits)(ListView);

export default ListView;
export {
    VeggiesList,
    FruitsList
};
```

Then update the router to:

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
  <IndexRedirect to='fruits' />
  <Route path='fruits' component={FruitsList} />
  <Route path='vegetables' component={VeggiesList} />
</Route>
```

Comment: Beautiful composition :)

Comment: +1 for exporting the original ListView too. This way, you can reuse it with other containers and test it like any other functional component.